Issues with flask migrate on initial migration
I was working on a flask app and was making a lot of database changes so I decided to take down my whole database, remove my migrations folder and rebuild. I created a new database but when i run flask db migrations, my models are detected, no migrations are ran and no tables are built. My initial migration isn't working.
my init.py-
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from flask_session import Session
import os

load_dotenv()

db = SQLAlchemy()
migrate = Migrate()

def create_app(environment='development'):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    
    if environment == 'development':
        app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = os.getenv("DEV_DATABASE_URL")
    else:
        app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = os.getenv("DATABASE_URL")
        
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

    app.config.from_object('config.Config')
    print("Loaded configuration:")
    print(app.config)

    print("SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI:", app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'])
    

    db.init_app(app)
    
    migrate.init_app(app, db)

    from app.models.perfume import Perfume, perfume_category
    from app.models.category import Category
    from app.models.brand import Brand
    Session(app)

    from app.routes.accounts import authenticate
    app.register_blueprint(authenticate)

    
    
    
    return app
# from app.routes import brand_routes, category_routes, perfume_routes

# # Register blueprints
# app.register_blueprint(brand_routes.bp)
# app.register_blueprint(category_routes.bp)
# app.register_blueprint(perfume_routes.bp)

what I get after running migrations -
   (.venv) tasniabhuiyan@Jasons-MBP server % flask db init

Loaded configuration:
<Config {'DEBUG': True, 'TESTING': False, 'PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS': None, 'SECRET_KEY': None, 'PERMANENT_SESSION_LIFETIME': datetime.timedelta(days=31), 'USE_X_SENDFILE': False, 'SERVER_NAME': None, 'APPLICATION_ROOT': '/', 'SESSION_COOKIE_NAME': 'session', 'SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN': None, 'SESSION_COOKIE_PATH': None, 'SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY': True, 'SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE': False, 'SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE': None, 'SESSION_REFRESH_EACH_REQUEST': True, 'MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH': None, 'SEND_FILE_MAX_AGE_DEFAULT': None, 'TRAP_BAD_REQUEST_ERRORS': None, 'TRAP_HTTP_EXCEPTIONS': False, 'EXPLAIN_TEMPLATE_LOADING': False, 'PREFERRED_URL_SCHEME': 'http', 'TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD': None, 'MAX_COOKIE_SIZE': 4093, 'SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI': 'postgresql://postgres:Imbegging@localhost/olfacto', 'SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS': False, 'SESION_PERMANENT': False, 'SESSION_REDIS': Redis<ConnectionPool<Connection<host=127.0.0.1,port=6379,db=0>>>, 'SESSION_TYPE': 'redis', 'SESSION_USE_SIGNER': True}>
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI: postgresql://postgres:Imbegging@localhost/olfacto
  Creating directory '/Users/tasniabhuiyan/Documents/olfacto/server/migrations'
  ...  done
  Creating directory
  '/Users/tasniabhuiyan/Documents/olfacto/server/migrations/versions' ...  done
  Generating
  /Users/tasniabhuiyan/Documents/olfacto/server/migrations/script.py.mako ...  done
  Generating /Users/tasniabhuiyan/Documents/olfacto/server/migrations/env.py ...  done
  Generating /Users/tasniabhuiyan/Documents/olfacto/server/migrations/README ...  done
  Generating /Users/tasniabhuiyan/Documents/olfacto/server/migrations/alembic.ini
  ...  done
  Please edit configuration/connection/logging settings in
  '/Users/tasniabhuiyan/Documents/olfacto/server/migrations/alembic.ini' before
  proceeding.
(.venv) tasniabhuiyan@Jasons-MBP server % flask db migrate -m "Initial migration"

Loaded configuration:
<Config {'DEBUG': True, 'TESTING': False, 'PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS': None, 'SECRET_KEY': None, 'PERMANENT_SESSION_LIFETIME': datetime.timedelta(days=31), 'USE_X_SENDFILE': False, 'SERVER_NAME': None, 'APPLICATION_ROOT': '/', 'SESSION_COOKIE_NAME': 'session', 'SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN': None, 'SESSION_COOKIE_PATH': None, 'SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY': True, 'SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE': False, 'SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE': None, 'SESSION_REFRESH_EACH_REQUEST': True, 'MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH': None, 'SEND_FILE_MAX_AGE_DEFAULT': None, 'TRAP_BAD_REQUEST_ERRORS': None, 'TRAP_HTTP_EXCEPTIONS': False, 'EXPLAIN_TEMPLATE_LOADING': False, 'PREFERRED_URL_SCHEME': 'http', 'TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD': None, 'MAX_COOKIE_SIZE': 4093, 'SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI': 'postgresql://postgres:Imbegging@localhost/olfacto', 'SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS': False, 'SESION_PERMANENT': False, 'SESSION_REDIS': Redis<ConnectionPool<Connection<host=127.0.0.1,port=6379,db=0>>>, 'SESSION_TYPE': 'redis', 'SESSION_USE_SIGNER': True}>
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI: postgresql://postgres:Imbegging@localhost/olfacto
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl PostgresqlImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume transactional DDL.
INFO  [alembic.env] No changes in schema detected.

I also already ran app.app_context in the terminal. What could the issue be?

What are the contents of your database? For this to work the database must be completely empty. If you already have your tables in there, then Flask-Migrate will decide that there is no need to migrate anything.

It was completely empty, no tables were built. It randomly worked 2 hrs later tho so I'm not sure why?
